# How to turn polygon into base layer in Surfer 14?

Tags: surfer

How do I turn a polygon I have drawn into a base layer in Surfer 14?

In Surfer 12, I used to be able to select my Base Map --> Digitise --> Select Polygon --> Digitise the Polygon Extents --> Export as Shapefile --> Import as Base Layer. However, in Surfer 14 it seems that when you select Digitise, you cannot select the polygon as the digitise function then switches off.

Does anyone have any tips on how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is just to draw the polygon as a base layer to start with (add an empty base layer, start editing, draw the polygon, stop editing).

If you've already drawn the polygon(s), then instead you can copy/cut them and paste them into a base layer (create the base layer, copy the polygon, start editing the base layer, paste the polygon and move it where you want it, stop editing).

If you want the polygons in a SHP file (or other file), you can export the base layer itself to a SHP file.

Exact instructions can be found on the Surfer KB article: [How Can I Draw Objects In Surfer, And Have Them Be Part Of A Base Map (To Move And Resize When I Move Or Rescale The Map)?](https://support.goldensoftware.com/hc/en-us/articles/226661988)